# How to access user infos from consumer.py django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-channels, djoser

I am building a social media app with react.js and django, django-rest-framework, [djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), django-channels==3.0.2..
well the problem is i want to make a notification system on friend request and on like of post and comment. The problem is I want to have some kind of security that when I send a request through the websocket from react, I want to check if the sender is the authenticated user,by sending the user id on the websockets, and comparing it to the logged in user's id.Since I can't get the `self.scope['user']` because i'm using **Djoser** for authentication, is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding a middleware in your django-channels app to authenticate and authorize the user,
if not follow these steps:
1)create a new file called middleware.py in the same folder as routing.py
2)add the following contents in the middleware.py
**[Note: The following implementation is from django-channels documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/authentication.html#custom-authentication)**

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections
from channels.auth import AuthMiddleware, AuthMiddlewareStack, UserLazyObject
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.sessions import CookieMiddleware, SessionMiddleware
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken

User = get_user_model()

"""[summary]
plucks the JWT access token from the query string and retrieves the associated user.
  Once the WebSocket connection is opened, all messages can be sent and received without
  verifying the user again. Closing the connection and opening it again 
  requires re-authorization.
for example: 
ws://localhost:8000/<route>/?token=<token_of_the_user>

"""


@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(scope):
    close_old_connections()
    query_string = parse_qs(scope['query_string'].decode())
    token = query_string.get('token')
    if not token:
        return AnonymousUser()
    try:
        access_token = AccessToken(token[0])
        user = User.objects.get(id=access_token['id'])
    except Exception as exception:
        return AnonymousUser()
    if not user.is_active:
        return AnonymousUser()
    return user


class TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddleware):
    async def resolve_scope(self, scope):
        scope['user']._wrapped = await get_user(scope)


def TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
    return CookieMiddleware(SessionMiddleware(TokenAuthMiddleware(inner)))
```

3)configure the middleware into the routes
3.1)open routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from django.urls import path
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from <base-app-name>.middleware import TokenAuthMiddlewareStack

from <app-name>.consumers import <consumer-name>

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path('<route>/', <consumer-name>),
        ]),
    ),
})
```

4)check for user in connect method of AsyncWebSocketConsumer

```
async def connect(self):
    user = self.scope['user']
    if user.is_anonymous:
        await self.close()
    else:
        <your logic>
```