# Django Channels TokenAuthMiddleware Unable to find Token in Database

Tags: python, django, django-channels, django-middleware

I'm so confused why my middleware isn't correctly getting a user based token query by key.

First I checked in my consumer, however the user in `self.scope` was an `AnonymousUser` (seen below in the code). This is reiterated when I set a foreign key in my receiver function, which raises the error: `ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10943cc10>": "ChatMessage.user" must be a "User" instance.`

Hence, I'm assuming the error is my middleware. I experimented with putting a print statement in `middleware.TokenAuthMiddleware.__call__`  after the `get_user` function is awaited and called, however, unexpectedly, the function returns an `AnonymousUser`. Both the user and the associated Token are created in the testcase's `setUp` and it's that token's key which is passed to the function.

Is the token string becoming malformed in `format_querystring`? The function is tested and passed, so I do not believe the token is becoming malformed there.

One thought is because the user and the token are being created in `setUp`, which is not `async`, it somehow is not aligned with the processes of the database look up in `get_user`. However changing that to `async` and wrapping the database calls in `database_sync_to_async` did not fix it, so I don't believe it's that either.

One idea is that not setting up my application correctly in the test, however based on [their tests](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/main/tests/test_generic_websocket.py#L73), it seems correct.

```py
# middleware.py

@database_sync_to_async
def get_user(token_key):
    """
    Get token from token key
    Parameters:
        token_key (str): Token key string
    Returns:
        if found, return associated User. Else, AnonymousUser
    """
    try:
        token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()
    else:
        return token.user


class TokenAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels
    E.g.
    ws://localhost:8000/<route>/?token=<token_of_the_user>

    Based on:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/49372334/5574063
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/65654519/5574063
    https://gist.github.com/rluts/22e05ed8f53f97bdd02eafdf38f3d60a#gistcomment-3166469

    TODO:
    implement:
    https://gist.github.com/rluts/22e05ed8f53f97bdd02eafdf38f3d60a#gistcomment-3174829
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361358/5574063
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        close_old_connections()
        query = self.format_querystring(scope['query_string'])
        token_key = query.get('token')
        scope['user'] = await get_user(token_key)
        return await super(TokenAuthMiddleware, self).__call__(scope, receive, send)

    def format_querystring(self, qs):
        """
        Convert byte querystring into dictionary.
        NOTE: will only take the first value.

        Parameters:
            qs (bstr): Querystring as bytes
        Returns:
            Dict of querystring
        """
        return {k: v[0] for k, v in dict(parse_qs(qs.decode().lower())).items()}


def TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
    return TokenAuthMiddleware(inner)


# consumer.py
    ...
    async def connect(self):
        good_user = 'user' in self.scope and self.scope['user'].is_authenticated
        print(good_user)
        ...

>>> False

# test.py
async def test_receive(self):
   # self.user and rest_framework Token created
   self.application = TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
   self.route = '/ws/chat/test-room/?token={}'.format(self.user.auth_token.key)
   communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(self.application, self.route)
   connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
   ...
```

I'm using `channels==3.0.3` and `Django==3.2.5`

---

EDIT:
Narrowed down the problem. The Token queryset is empty when it reaches `get_user`. E.i.

```
# printed from the test
<QuerySet [<Token: bca50384e55d88fdc109c73b29c5d0745c5dd379>]>
# printed from within the function
<QuerySet []>
```

Why would the queryset empty for the middleware/consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [Django's TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) solved the issue. TransactionTestCase is further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450533/difference-between-testcase-and-transactiontestcase-classes-in-django-test).

The questions [Database errors in Django when using threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948537/database-errors-in-django-when-using-threading), [Test database not keeping data during Django Channels Pytest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175352/test-database-not-keeping-data-during-django-channels-pytest-test), and [Django channels 2, accessing db in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136564/django-channels-2-accessing-db-in-tests) led me to a working solution.

I don't fully understand why forcing transactions to be atomic is the solution, but oh well.